# Why the induced orientation need the manifold is connected

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from 18th page of  Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. In my view, the induced orientation does not connected. Assume $(U_\alpha, x_\alpha)$ is orientation of $M_1$, then $(\varphi(U_\alpha), \varphi\circ x_\alpha)$ is a orientation of $M_2$. Seemly, the connected is not used in here.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectedness assumption isn't required to define the induced orientation, but is instead required to make sense of of the last sentence: in the case where $M,N$ are not connected, a diffeomorphism $\varphi:M\to N$ may be neither orientation reversing nor orientation preserving.

As a general note, in many topics it's common to assume connectedness as a matter of convenience, even when it is not strictly necessary. Extending to the nonconnected case (by treating connected components individually) is usually trivial and/or not particularly useful.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is correct, but really not very relevant to the author's purpose of giving a meaningful definition of orientation-preserving vs orientation-reversing diffeomorphisms.

If $\varphi:M_1\to M_2$ is a diffeomorphism and say $M_1$ is not connected, notice that for any connected component $C$ of $M_1$ that the restriction $\varphi\vert_C : C\to \varphi(C)$ is a diffeomorphism between connected manifolds. The restriction can preserve or reverse orientation by the author's definition.

So for each connected component, $\varphi$ may preserve or reverse orientation. This is the usual way to discuss disconnected manifolds: Break them down into their connected components and talk about those.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ has $n$ different connected components and if $M$ is orientable, each connected component is orientable and $M$ has $2^n$ different possible orientations.

Thus, if $f : M_1 \to M_2$ is a diffeomorphism between oriented manifolds with finite connected components, $f$ could be

- **orientation preserving** ($1$ case)
- non orientation preserving ($2^n -1$ cases)

In case there is just one component, being non orientation preserving leads to only one case. In that last case, we say that $f$ is **orientation reversing** and this is not ambiguous which orientation is induced on $M_2$.

Comment: "Orientation reversing" would also cover the case where $f$ reversed orientation on all $n$ components of $M_1$. It's not restricted to the connected/single component case.